# Use of malloc in my method

Tags: c, malloc

Hi guys I'm really struggling with the use of malloc in general. I wrote this method that, given a path, returns the file name. To do so I wrote this:

```
const char* getFileName(const char *path) {
    char *filename = strrchr(path, '/');      
    char *name = NULL;
    char *start, *finish;

    if(filename){
        start = strstr(filename, "/" );       
        if (start) {
            start += strlen("/");
            finish = strstr(start, "." );           
            if (finish) {
                name = (char *) malloc(finish - start + 1);
                memcpy(name, start, finish - start);
                name[finish - start] = '\0';                
            }
        }
    } else {
        finish = strstr(path, ".");
        if (finish) {
            name = (char *) malloc(finish - path + 1);
            memset(name,0,sizeof(finish -path + 1));
            memcpy(name, path, finish - path);
            name[finish - path] = '\0';                     
        }
    }

    return name;
}
```

What I'd like to know is if filename, start and finish needs a malloc to avoid trouble with my memory. In general I was wondering if, when using a strrchar or a strstr do you need to allocate memory or not

Comment: The variables `filename`, `start`, and `finish` *all* points into the string provided by `path`. You should not allocate memory for them, at least not if you then just go around a reassign the pointers. There's also no need to copy the parts, as then the pointers and arrays would become completely unrelated and you won't be able to use arithmetic on them. So in short, no you should not allocate any more memory for the other pointers.

Comment: Minor: In C, it is common to call `getFileName(const char *path)` a function and not a method - at least that is what the C spec calls it.

Comment: The line `memset(name,0,sizeof(finish -path + 1));` should be removed : at best it's not needed - at worst, it'll attempt to overwrite memory outside of the bounds of the array.

Comment: `sizeof(finish -path + 1)` has a constant value, perhaps 4 or 8. (same as `sizeof(ptrdiff_t)`.  Certainly not what OP wants or needs.

Comment: Note: obtaining the 'base name' from a 'path'  is already, cleanly handled via the call to `basename()`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to return a null terminated array without changing the input `path` (since it is const) then you have to allocate a new string as you have done. And please document that the caller is responsible for freeing it when it no longer needs it to avoid memory leaks...

But then your function actually does 2 unrelated operation: search the limits of the filename part **and** allocates memory for a copy of it. For separation of concerns (and for the sake of simpler tests), I would make one function for the first part with 2 output variables for the beginning and the end of the filename part:

```
int getFileName(const char *path, const char **beg, const char **end) {
    *beg = strrchr(path, '/');
    const char *finish;      

    if(*beg){
        *beg += 1;      // just skip over the '/' character
    }
    finish= strrchr(*beg, ".");
    if (NULL == finich) {
        finish = *beg + strlen(*beg)
    }
    if (end != NULL) *end = finish;     // optionaly returns a pointer to the end
    return finish - *beg;  // returns the length of the filename part
}
```

No allocation is involved here, and the caller will receive, a pointer to the beginning of the filename part, its length and optionaly a pointer to its end if it passes a non null pointer for `end`. For many use cases, there will be no need to allocate anything even in the caller part.

Comment: Alternatively you could write a function which does not do any allocation, but only the search and copy. I think that is the best alternative. You'd have `void getFileName (const char* path, char* dst, size_t* length)`. Optionally an extra parameter to specify the maximum buffer length of `dst`. I don't think a function which only fiddles around with pointers in the caller code makes a good API.